# How to save and recieve String in thingspeak.com?

Tags: arduino-uno, iot

I know how to save data like(`1,2,2.3,65.2`).

I was wondering if its possible to save and retrieve data like(`'AP09BN7886'`)(`String`) in thingspeak.com?
I am sending data to thingspeak.com via esp8266 connected to my arduino UNO using AT commands.

Can I also retrieve data from thingspeak.com using esp8266 in Arduino UNO?

Answer (score 1):

The [arduino examples](https://github.com/iobridge/ThingSpeak-Arduino-Examples) from thingspeak.com on GitHub shows an example to handle string data via ethernet. This could be a perfect starting point for you.

```c
//...

// Create HTTP POST Data
tsData = "api_key="+thingtweetAPIKey+"&status="+tsData;

client.print("POST /apps/thingtweet/1/statuses/update HTTP/1.1\n");
client.print("Host: api.thingspeak.com\n");
client.print("Connection: close\n");
client.print("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n");
client.print("Content-Length: ");
client.print(tsData.length());
client.print("\n\n");

client.print(tsData);

//...
```